# How to refer environment variable in terminal command?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I am new to Linux world, here i am trying to pass the env variable in command to aws in this way

```
sudo aws s3 cp s3://bucket/path/to/file.sh file.sh
```

Should download the `file.sh` to my local, here i want the user to set env variable `FILE_PATH` and use it while downloading file.

```
echo $FILE_PATH
```

displays

```
s3://bucket/path/to/file.sh
```

But when I do

```
sudo aws s3 cp $FILE_PATH file.sh
```

the file is corrupted and not downloading actual file, how do I refer env in this command?

Comment: Quote your file path > `"$FILE_PATH"`, otherwise special chars or spaces within the file path will cause problems.

Comment: Try `echo`ing the command, is `$FILE_PATH` expanded correctly?

Comment: @Melebius i tried sudo aws s3 cp "echo $FILE_PATH" file.sh still fails

Comment: @Melebius Got it echo sudo aws s3 cp "$FILE_PATH " /home/scripts/file.sh | bash - thanks for help

Comment: They meant to just `echo $FILE_PATH` to make sure it's being properly expanded and is not malformed. I'm no expert, but your final command seems dangerous.